# Trying to resize the navbar, change font size, and center the text

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create a navbar for my website.  I've gone through the CSS and tried to resize the navbar and align the text.  I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Here is a section of the css.

```
    .nav {
font-family: "Indie Flower", serif;
font-size: larger;
color: white;
}

#navwrapper{
width = 100%
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style : none
font-family: "Indie Flower", Arial;
background-color: red;
height = 10px;
text-align = "center";
}
```

Also the HTML

```
<body>

<div id="main" class="main" style ="text-align = center">
</div>

<div id = "navwrapper">
    <p class = "nav">Holder</>
</div>
<br>
<iframe src = "http://chrisfoose.blogspot.com" width = "100%" height = "300" frameborder = "0">
<p>Unfortunately your browser does not support dynamic content.</p>
</iframe>   

</div>
</body>
```

Also, a link to what the current results are:

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/chrisfoose/pen/VLEwVM)

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var imgSrcArr = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/running_horse-wide.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/colorful_background-wide.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/moonlight_cruise-wide.jpg"]

var imgSrcArr = ["background/000.jpg", "background/001.jpg", "background/002.jpg", "background/003.jpg", "background/004.jpg"]

window.onload = function() {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSrcArr[randNum] + "')"
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One);
@import "compass/css3";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech+Mono);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
 svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.center {
  float: center;
}
div.main {
  margin: auto;
  ;
  height: 500px;
  ;
  width: 1000px;
  background-position: center;
  backgroud-repeat: no-repeat border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#vid {
  width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
#buttonred {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #8A0808;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonblue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #4000FF;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttongreen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #088A08;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonpink {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonorange {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonback {
  witdth: 100px;
  height 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
;
table.center {
  ;
  background-color: white;
  ;
  margin.left: auto;
  ;
  margin.right: auto;
  ;
}
table.center {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 300px;
  color: white;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Terminal, Times New Roman;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
p.bio {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 50px margin-left: 50px
}
div.enclose {
  margin-top: 50px margin-left: 50px
}
td.bio {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
table.bio {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 50px;
}
table.video {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
table.graphics {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px border-color: white;
}
td.graphics {
  border: 1px solid white;
  align: center;
}
#videobanner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}
p.video {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
p.menu {
  font-family: "Indie Flower", serif;
  font-color: white font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.nav {
  font-family: "Indie Flower", serif;
  font-size: larger;
  color: white;
}
#navwrapper {
  width=100% float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none font-family: "Indie Flower", Arial;
  background-color: red;
  height=10px;
  text-align="center";
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="main" class="main" style="text-align = center">


    <div id="navwrapper">
      <p class="nav">Holder
        </>
    </div>
    <br>
    <iframe src="http://chrisfoose.blogspot.com" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0">
      <p>Unfortunately your browser does not support dynamic content.</p>
    </iframe>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You were closing off your main `div` prematurely and your `css` was incorrectly formatted. Use colons not equals signs in css.

Here is the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpBOVB).